# Reading backwards with ifstream stops reading after file position -620 bytes

Tags: c++, ifstream

I am reading a file using ifstream. I am reading the file from the end of the file. I have a loop that subtracts one from a counter variable. Each iteration of the loop I seek to that position relative from the end of the file using the `ios::end` constant. Everything works fine, except that it stops reading the file after -620 bytes from the end of the file.

```
long fileposition;
char magicvalue[4];
while(keeplooking)
{
    infile.seekg(fileposition, std::ios::end);
    infile.read(magicvalue,4);

    fileposition -= 0x01;
}
```

I've stepped through with my debugger, and everything is working fine except after I loop. The fileposition variable keeps on getting smaller and smaller, but when I call the read function, the values of magicvalue are never changed. I am looking at the file I am reading in the hex editor and following along, but once again, it stops  reading.

Does anyone have any thoughts on why this would happen?

Comment: Why are you reading four bytes, but only decrementing the position by one? Also, how do you initialise fileposition?

Comment: `fileposition` is uninitialized.  If you do initialize it to something, then you don't suppose that might be pertinent to the question?  For all we know, you may be setting it to file offset 620.  You forgot to tell us exactly how large your file is.  For all we know it may be exactly 620 bytes long.

Comment: in my particular case file position is initialized to -0xB2. I am doing a search for a value that indicates the start of some important information, but it is always towards the end.